# react-hot-toast custom positioning overlay

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am using react-hot-toast npm package for my notifications and i have created custom card with the help of toast.custom() function.
I need to overlap notifications on top of each card.but there is no options given to do that.With new version (2.0) they have given the option to customize the position with container styles for  component but not for the toast.custom() function.If someone can help me much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no codes.I am asking if there is.So if anyone knows please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide enough code and you will better solution the problem.
and you can follow this code
**Install with NPM** : npm install react-hot-toast
**Install with Yarn** : yarn add react-hot-toast

```
import toast, { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
const notify = () => toast('Here is your toast.');
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={notify}>Make me a toast</button>
      <Toaster />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your answer does not actually answer this question. Please make sure to answer to at least refer to the `toast.custom()` function

Comment: Only issue is i need know if there is to code to do so.its more into css.toast.custom() .But i need to inject overlapping css to this.